# App refuses to connect to Parse backend

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am working on an app called TobaccoRoad that uses a library project called BestApproach. It uses a Parse backend to display custom generated content and handle push notifications. Everything was working pretty alright until a few days ago, when I must have messed up some settings somewhere and it no longer seems to be making the connection to the parse systems. I'm quite sure it's a local issue, because my second tester phone, which has not had updated code pushed to it in a few days, is still receiving notifications and can view that custom content.

The weird thing is, even after clearing my workspace and starting fresh from the (definitely good) code my employer gave me, and following all the tutorials and troubleshooting guides on Parse.com (see https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#installations/Android; https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications) I'm still not connecting to Parse. I haven't made any significant changes that I can recall, so I'm at a loss as to what might be causing this.

I know it's not an issue of a bad applicationID or clientKey, because even substituting random strings into the Parse.initialize call gave the same results, and a logcat error about not being able to authenticate.

Here are the relevant bits from my manifest files, first for the library project...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.bestapproach.lib"
      android:versionCode="8"
      android:versionName="1.6.1">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.BA" >
        <activity android:name="com.bestapproach.lib.SplashActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                  android:configChanges="orientation"
                  android:theme="@style/Theme.BA.Splash">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    <!--Declarations for all of my Activities...-->
        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
          </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>        
    </manifest>
```

And the manifest is exactly the same for my dependent project, with the exception of where I define a custom receiver at the end:

```
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:name="com.bestapproach.lib.MyCustomReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.bestapproach.lib.UPDATE_STATUS" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And here's the code for the onCreate() method in my main activity (SplashActivity) where the Parse service is initialized:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

String parseClientId = getString(R.string.parse_client_id);
String parseAppId = getString(R.string.parse_app_id);

//debug output
Log.v("parse should be initializing...", parseAppId+" "+parseClientId);

if (!("".equals(parseClientId) || "".equals(parseAppId))) {
    Parse.initialize(this, parseAppId, parseClientId);
    PushService.subscribe(this, "", MenuActivity.class);
    PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, SplashActivity.class);
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
    ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());

    final Activity a = this; 

    // Fetches content if it doesn't exist.
    StoreManager sm = StoreManager.getInstance(a);
    ParseStoreManager psm = ParseStoreManager.getInstance(a);

    return;
}

}
```

Suggestions I've found that seem like they may be on track with what I need include running `Parse.initialize()` in the `onCreate()` of every activity, which I don't really want to do as there are a lot of them and that would be a lot of duplicated code, or generating an Application object and running it from there. Everything I've tried in relation to that has ended up breaking once I add it to my manifest file, due to TobaccoRoad's dependencies on the library project.

I know, it's a lot to dig through, but any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks everybody.

Comment: You have compared your `AppId` and `ClientId` with you actual from the parse cloud?

Answer (score 0):

Possible fix:

Change this line

```
 if (!("".equals(parseClientId) || "".equals(parseAppId))) {
    Parse.initialize(this, parseAppId, parseClientId);
```

to this:

```
if (!("".equals(parseClientId) || "".equals(parseAppId))) {
    Parse.initialize(SplashActivity.this, parseAppId, parseClientId);
```

Comment: That didn't work...since it's just happening on my phone, I've just been manually inputting the values into my version that I'm running. That's working for now. Thanks anyways. I'll update if I figure something else out.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is that

```
ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
```

accepts the intent from that activity from your SplashActivity and from the application scope
Also, you initialize parse from the activity which we generally don't do.
We try initialize parse from the Application class so it has the context of the Application scope and not of the Activity Scope.
I recommend you to create an Application class and include the parse code in the onCreate of the Application...which you would need to do only once.

Or, you can create some BaseActivities and make all your activities in the application extend to that. This will save you from writing duplicate code...this is just in case you are bound not to create an Application class.

Pardon me for anything wrong...I am new in answering.

Comment: accepts the intent from that activity from your SplashActivity and *NOT* from the application scope